# Multiple DataTables in one page with differents parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have two dataTables on the same page, like this example:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html

Until no problem ..

It shares many parameters in common, for example for buttons or language

```
$('table').DataTable({
  language: {
    search: "",
    searchPlaceholder: "Search ...",
    sLengthMenu:"_MENU_",
    sInfo:"_TOTAL_ elmt",
    infoFiltered: "",
    sInfoEmpty: "0 elmt",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sPrevious": "<",
      "sNext": ">"
    }
  }
});
```

However, I wish to give them different `pageLength` sizes and different tries,
How can I do ?

Knowing that the **ID of the first table** is `table-one` and the **ID of the second** is `table-two`

Comment: Why don't you just do `$('#table-one').DataTable()` and `$('#table-two').DataTable()` and give everyone it's own params?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Because there is more parameter in common than of different parameter, so I wanted to avoid the redundancy of the code

Comment: If there is even 1 different parameter then you need to duplicate all of the code, there's no going through that unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
// create an object with your settings for the first table
var dataTableOptions = {
  language: {
    search: "",
    searchPlaceholder: "Search ...",
    sLengthMenu:"_MENU_",
    sInfo:"_TOTAL_ elmt",
    infoFiltered: "",
    sInfoEmpty: "0 elmt",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sPrevious": "<",
      "sNext": ">"
    }
  }
};

// initialize that table
$('#table1').DataTable(dataTableOptions);

// modify whatever settings you need to in the object you created
dataTableOptions.language.sLengthMenu = "some new value";

// use the modified object to initialize the second table
$('#table2').DataTable(dataTableOptions);
```

Comment: This is only for translation, how do you set diferent length pages?

Comment: @Dani you should read the comments "// modify whatever settings you need to in the object you created" the given property was simply an example. You can change any property thats needed

Comment: Yeah i understand know, i was thinking in json traslations of datatable... Sorry and good answer